# Unit Tests: The type "Status" exists in two projects

Tags: c#, .net, types

I'm writing unit tests for my program and I encountered an error of my type existing in two different projects. I tried to overcome it by adding a project name to the code: `var status = CommunicationsServer.Status()` but then it says that there exist no Status() type there.

Please help

[image]

Here are the first few lines of CommunicationsServer.Status class:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://www.mini.pw.edu.pl/ucc/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mini.pw.edu.pl/ucc/", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class Status {

    private ulong idField;

    private StatusThread[] threadsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public ulong Id {
        get {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }
//further code 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Without additional context of both types in `CommunicationsServer` and `TaskManager`, it's hard to determine a solution. Why not add a `using` statement to the `CommunicationsServer` library? If it's a static class, put `using static` before the namespace and static type. Also possible that If you actually typed `var status = CommunicationsServer.Status()` it's not a static type and VS doesn't know what you're referencing. Please provide additional information on the conflicting types (namespace, class declaration, etc) and you may get better help.

Comment: What do you mean by context? CommunicationServer and TaskManager are both projects that contain a Status class of type `public partial class Status` I made a constructor to that class, I shouldn't need my class to be static for it. How to implement using statement?

Comment: I edited my question with some more info

Comment: After your edit I have some additional questions. Is this Status class auto generated from some XML to C# tool? What is the namespace at the top of the file?

Comment: Yes: `using CommunicationsServer;`

Comment: I don't think that's the right thing. There should be `namespace SomeNameHere` at or near the top. `namespace CommunicationsServer { public partial class Status{ }}` is how it is structured in the auto-generated file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108105/discussion-between-tyler-standishman-and-aleksander-lipka).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two different types, they must be separated by a namespace. If you have two projects, `ProjectOne` and `ProjectTwo`, with the same type `MyType`, then there is literally no way to differentiate the type. I'm not sure how it works underneath, but I was able to implement this, and unable to get Visual Studio to compile my reference to the type in a third project `ProjectThree`. Exactly as you have in your question.

For some reason, auto-generated xml to C# files do not always put a namespace around the classes that it generates. Simply provide a unique namespace, relevant to the project and you should be good to go.

In your CommunicationsServer generated file:

```
namespace CommunicationsServer.Xsd 
{
    public partial class Status() 
    {

    }
}
```

And in the TaskManager generated file:

```
namespace TaskManager.Xsd 
{
    public partial class Status() 
    {

    }
}
```

Then in `ProjectThree` you can either put a using statement `using CommunicationsServer.Xsd` or fully qualify the type: `var status = new CommunciationsServer.Xsd.Status();`

Comment: Omg! It works! Thank you very much for your time and effort