# Type exists in both error sharing project references and giving each project it's own DLL build of a library when building

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have multiple projects and everything was working ok prior, but I had to download a UI framework package + change the source. I decided to include the DLL's in each project, reference them per project, and now trying to build a solution that references multiple projects blows up saying "type is in both" but I don't understand the problem. Using DLL's, shared projects, why is Visual Studio and the build so confused and can't figure out how to handle this?

The reason I used shared project references too is so I can use code & classes from one project in another and we have class libraries too.

Is there an easy way to fix this?  It worked fine as a nuget package so why does using built DLL's isolated per project present a problem, it's the exact same thing.

Comment: Have you checked all projects uses the same version, also clean your project before the build. appears to be multiple versions of assemblies are referenced across your solution,

Comment: Ya, same version. I built the DLL myself from another project, and same with my shared project references same error. I also do clean build and have referenced several forum threads. I am not sure why it gets confused it is one project or one DLL and it can't figure it out.

Comment: I believe something to do with namespace conflict, if you could check the complete error message you should be able to find out which namespace is creating this issue, I think this ticket explained in details how to resolve these type of issues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386969/unit-tests-the-type-status-exists-in-two-projects/36392201

Comment: I completely removed the nuget package I downloaded, customized/compiled, and went back to using nuget and the cascading failure effect went away. So I am not sure why I can't do this in VS...it has an issue with me taking a package and using it in all my projects...? Because nuget is encapsulating it somehow but when I do it all my builds get confused and think there are multiple versions of it I guess?

Comment: I doubt previously your project still holding reference in packages.config so it download packages automatically?

Comment: I think Visual studio just got confused so I reverted my source and slowly did things one by one and it seems to be ok. Some of the errors didn't make sense and never appeared before, but it seems to cache output from designer + packages or something, even in nuget I found I had to uninstall/re-install too...wasted hours but got to where I needed to be starting over and flushing out cache/re-installing packages and manually adding my own dll's. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seemed to be related to Visual studio caching and how packages are managed so I reverted by source code to start over again. I uninstalled/re-installed nuget packages, manually added my own DLL's, re-built everything from scratch, and it finally worked.

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.

Comment: Ok, done. Didn't realize I also had to do that. Thanks!